# SWIFT code dataWithContentsOfFile broken with update to XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Ever since the latest update to XCode the following two lines of codes have compile errors. Can anybody please advice me on the adjustments I need to make to get the program to compile and run again?

```
        var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData) archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use (iOS < 8.0)

```
NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path)
```

or (iOS >= 7.0)

```
var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

If you create a new SpriteKit sample project in XCode 6.1, you will see the changes.

Comment: That fixed the first line of code error (thankyou). However the second line is not compiling with an error marked immediately before "archiver.setClass...." saying consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;. Any ideas on this line?

Comment: Add a semicolon after sceneData): NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData); archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. See [answer] for writing more detailed posts the site is expecting. For instance you want to explain how this line is better than the currently selected answer posted 6 months ago.